# Azure Event Hub - EventProcessorClient on specific partition

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

I am using the EventProcessorClient to read events from an event hub. How can I restrict this client to read from a specific partition?

I create it like this:

```
EventProcessorClientBuilder eventProcessorClientBuilder = new EventProcessorClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)
                .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
                .processEvent(IncomingEventProcessor.processEvent)
                .processError(processError)
                .checkpointStore(new BlobCheckpointStore(blobContainerAsyncClient));

        EventProcessorClient eventProcessorClient = eventProcessorClientBuilder.buildEventProcessorClient();
```

The function referencer in "processEvent" will be called for all events on the event hub - for all partitions. I can check which partition the event was related to in that function, but I wish to only receive the events that is from a specific partition.

Is this possible using the EventProcessorClient?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by using the EventProcessorClient, however you can use the EventHubConsumerAsyncClient class to achieve what you are looking for [see doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubconsumerasyncclient?view=azure-java-stable),
It contains a [receiveFromPartition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubconsumerasyncclient.receivefrompartition?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_messaging_eventhubs_EventHubConsumerAsyncClient_receiveFromPartition_java_lang_String_com_azure_messaging_eventhubs_models_EventPosition_) method

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `EventProcessorClient` is selfbalancing - i.e. it will distribute the partitions across the number of instances connected to the event hub.